# agregar una columan nueva con ifelse r

Tags: r, rstudio

hola tengo dos tablas

| id | n compras | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |

y otra tabla que me señala los ingresos de las personas y el numero de integrantes de la familia

| id | income | family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.5 | 2 |
| 2 | 10.5 | 4 |
| 3 | 20.5 | 5 |
| 4 | 18.5 | 3 |

quiero crear dos nuevas columnas en la primera tabla, una que señale el income por id y otra los integrantes de familia por id:

intenté usar el siguiente código:

```
primeratabla$income <- if(primeratabla$id == segundatabla$id){segundatabla$income}
```

pero me aparecieron los siguientes warnings y errors

Warning in `==.default`(trans$hhid, demo$hhid) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Warning in is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
Warning in if (trans$hhid == demo$hhid) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error: Assigned data `if (...) NULL` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 4470 rows.
x Assigned data has 516 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

hay alguna forma de realizar lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: Con left_join(df1,df2), obtienes lo deseado. La función left_join() es del paquete dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás una opción que puedes intentar es lo siguiente:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by ="id")
```

Comment: Hola Isaac Bravo, las publicaciones que son sólo código sin ninguna explicación de lo que hacen o cómo resuelven el problema, se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para los usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir una breve descripción del código, dónde debe ponerse y qué es lo que hace para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Completa el [tour] y lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el feedback Alvaro Montoro!